# Flutter notification badge listen when update

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I am new to flutter, I would like to make a chat app with notification badge that listen to incoming message and remove badge when I click. How do I make it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [flutter badge](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) plugin and firestore for remove badge when click

Some example code:-

```
bool _showbadge = false;
.
.
.
.
if(int.parse(snapshot1.data["chat_count"]) > 0){
                    _showbadge = true;
                  }else{
                    _showbadge = false;
                  }

Badge(
      showBadge: _showbadge,
      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 0.55, end: 0.155),
      animationType: BadgeAnimationType.scale,
      badgeContent: Text("${snapshot1.data["chat_count"]}"),
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to look at into this? Hope this helps
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html